# Package Installer has stopped

Tags: android

I am developing some app for android which worked well untill this evening.
However the app is working well in emulator but on Archos 80 G9 tablet with android 3.2.80 I got this error

```
The application Package installer (process com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

Also here is my manifest XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="oni.dani"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" 

          />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true"

         >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.android.onidani.Dashboard" >
            <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.android.onidani.KlasaPrikazBaze"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.android.onidani.Dashboard"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.android.onidani.OniDaniActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I tired several times, uninstalling and "installing"...Still same happens.

Comment: how are you starting the install? Thru adb?

Comment: Copy .apk to device and install from tablet.

Comment: Try connecting your device to DDMS while uninstalling/installing app, see if you can get more error message from Logcat.

Comment: Haha, lame mistake, Dashboard activity was defined twice :) Thank you everyone and please close thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is occuring because you have declared your `Dashboard` activity twice.

```
<activity android:name="com.android.onidani.Dashboard"></activity>
```

Comment: I haven't declared any activity twice. But still I'm facing the issue. [Manifest](http://paste.ofcode.org/BtdUKwUeuk7XwbP9CpajMg)

Answer (score 3):

You should add permission declaration in your manifest file. E.g

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

error: **'unfortunately package installer has stopped'**. This happens when application needs permissions like location, phone call, Read external storage, write external storage etc. If permission is not defined in the manifest file then i get this kind of error message.

Add permission in manifest file according to your need

i need read/write file so i added below permission (outside of application)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in my situation i was passing empty array to requestPermissions. so check if your array is'not empty (String[] permissions)